# Google Drive API - How to get file type (Document, Spreadsheet, Drawing, Presentation or Folder) with File ID

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I may be be missing something very obvious, but without parsing some of the values, how do you get the file's type (document, spreadsheet, presentation or drawing) in the Google Drive API with the file ID.

I need to get the list of files from a shared folder - no prob.

I then need to process these files based on their file type - so document, spreadsheet, drawing, presentation or folder.  This is problematic because I can't figure out how to get the file type.

What I have tried so far:

**Get files list in a folder:**

```
$obj = $service->children->listChildren($folderId);
```

No problem.

**Iterate through files and get file metadata with File ID:**

```
foreach ($obj->items as $item):
    $fileId = $item->id;
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
    // Rest of code here
endforeach;
```

No Problem.

**Get file type**

I can't figure out how to get file type from the $file object.

I end up doing a messy work around:

```
if (strpos($file->embedLink,'document') !== false) $fileType = 'document';
if (strpos($file->embedLink,'spreadsheet') !== false) $fileType = 'spreadsheet';
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried at the very least.

Comment: Hi Feign - added my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

So, simply enough it is:

```
$file->mimeType.
```

You get:

```
application/vnd.google-apps.document    
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
```

etcetera

Was scanning over it too quickly.